# Deploying text files with Java, where should they be located?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a Java application that reads some data from a text file called Countries.txt. In Netbeans the file is under the Project-level folder. Now that I have tested it in Netbeans I am ready to deploy and test it as a jar file on different machines. The dist folder does not include the text file and I have  manually copied it to the dist (folder as the jar file) and dist\lib folders but I get a 'file not found' error.
My file has no path information, just ...

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Countries.txt"));
```

With a jar file where should supporting files go?

Comment: Next to the `.jar`

Comment: You could store the files in the jar (so called _resources_) if they are read-only. The reader will be slightly different.

Comment: @Professor901 I have placed it in the same folder as the jar but I still get the error

Comment: @JoopEggen. unfortunately they need to be editable for users to customise.

Comment: Odd one. 
I added a quick bit of code to create a text file with no path name and then searched for it. It was stored in my top-level user profile folder. I will dig about and find out why windows decide to shove it there.
I have a work around of using JFileChooser to manually find it but that seems overly complex.

Comment: The file would be located in the current working directory. So, before running your Java application, use the CD command and specify the correct directory.

Answer (score 2):

The "new File(..)" and similar constructs like "new FileReader(..)" always construct the path relative to the current working directory (unless you pass an absolute path as parameter). Within an IDE this is mostly the project's root folder (at least in eclipse, from your description I assume also in Netbeans).

But when you run it ouside the IDE the current working directory is the directory where you started java.exe.

To avoid these inconsistencies I recommend to place the files in question into a folder which is declared to be in the classpath (-cp command line argument or defined in the manifest.mf within the jar). Then you can load a file as resource:

```
 this.getClass().getResourceAsStream( "myFile.txt");
```

**Edit:**

Above approach is recommended for read-only resources. Such resources can even be placed in the root folder inside your jar file.

But if you have to edit the file (and save it back somewhere) the things get more complicated.

A standalone java application usually has a folder layout like:

```
myProject
    bin
        start.bat
    lib
        myApp.jar
    cfg
        myApp.properties
```

By double clicking on the start.bat you will find the current directory to be myProject/bin. Knowing this it's easy to navigate e.g. to the cfg directory:

```
new File(../cfg/myApp.properties)
```

This is valid for your runtime installation. But within the IDE you probably have another layout:

```
myProject
    prod
        bin
            start.bat
        cfg
            myApp.properties
        src
            ...
    test
        ...
    lib
        myApp.jar
```

If you want to keep the same hard coded relative path when running in the IDE you have to configure the working directory in the lauch configuration in the IDE. Following the example above (example from eclipse):

```
Working directory = "${workspace_loc:MyProject/prod/bin}".
```

In eclipse this can be done in Run/RunConfigurations on the second Tab "Arguments". I am sure Netbeans has such a possibility too.

Comment: That only gives you an InputStream. The OP said he wants to edit the file. (Though that's confusing, because he uses a BufferedReader so I don't know how he intends to edit it.)

Comment: I was probably not clear in my post. The application is for logging contacts in JOTI, the Jamboree on the Internet text files contain customisable data for users to adjust for their needs such as group names, locations and achievement levels. I need to keep them as easily accessible text files for editing via notepad or similar and so storing them in the jar would make this slightly more complex.

Comment: I answered the question in the title of this post: Where should the files be located. What then afterwards is done with the InputStream is not part of this question.

Comment: See my edits: I added a second possibility which is more convenient for editing files.

Comment: If he doesn't double-click on start.bat, but types it into Windows->Run dialog box, then the current directory is not where start.bat is, and your solution won't work.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of digging about on SO and other places I found a way of returning the absolute path and added it to my general Utilities class. It seems to work  on all the machine I have used it windows and linux.

```
 /**
 * Returns a String representing the path name of the jar and therefore the
 * base locations of the application for supporting files.
 *
 * @return String representing the base location of the application.
 */
public static String getPathName() {
    String fullPath = "";
    int endOfPath = 0;
    try {
        fullPath = new File(JOTI_App.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()).toString();
        endOfPath = fullPath.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar);
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return fullPath.substring(0, endOfPath);
}
```

Comment: I think instead of doing string manipulation with the index of the file separator char, you can simply use Paths.getParent().

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer above: the current directory is always the directory where java.exe is started. And never the directory where the jar is located (well, except you have started java.exe in the jar directory)! So your answer is completely wrong in this context (and the java doc of your helper method as well).Please delete this answer.

Comment: @Heri I don't think Andy's answer is wrong. It depends on how you interpret certain terminology. When you say "the directory where java.exe is started" do you mean the current working directory? This is not what Andy means by "the path name of the jar and therefore the base locations". He appears to consider the "base location" as the location of the jar, and is not interested in what the "current working directory is".

Comment: I appreciate that this is an international group so i will try to be clearer. If I open a cmd console and paste in the pathname from the build process the application looks for files in my home directory and not where the jar is located. I understand that this is because I am not running it from the jar location but the home folder and this is the 'current directory'. The getPathName method seems to work for all methods of starting the application so I am happy with it. The term current directory seems to be the confusion, I never mentioned current directory only the jar directory.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException: It is still wrong. "base locations of the application for supporting files": What should this mean? Look, we have two concepts in java: One is the java classpath, the other is the OS PATH. The first concept plays only a role if you load a file as resource. And if the "base location" (as it is returned from above method) is used for loading a resource you will not be able to load this resource unless this base location is part of the java classpath (as defined on the starter command line or in the manifest). So its useless to have a method for dynamically finding this path.

Comment: (continued...)    The second is relevant if you create a File or Path object (e.g. new File( ../cfg/my.properties), unless you pass an absolute path. A non absolute path is always relative to the current directory, and the current directory is the one where you startet java. I introduced the "current directory" in this discussion because without this term you will never understand the file finding strategy of java.