# file not found on path ""src/test/resources/"

Tags: java, file, unit-testing, io

my java test code tries to get to a file in my project folders

but I get IO exception:

```
   String fileContents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(
            Paths.get("src/test/resources/SenegalAndBulgariaConfig.txt")));


   String fileContents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(
            Paths.get("src/")));
```

It used to work, but not anymore:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: src/test/resources/SenegalAndBulgariaConfig.txt

    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3152)
```

though it exist:

[image]

Comment: Does the file definitely exist in that location?

Comment: You can't depend on a file system.  You need to load files as resources from classpath.

Comment: Is that a spring project?

Comment: @TwiN gradle project

Comment: Pretty sure you need an absolute path, not just from `src`. Have a quick look at this [readAllBytes code](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.nio.file/Files/Java_Files_readAllBytes_Path_path_.htm).

Comment: @duffymo it's test code, that's why load resources is problematic

Comment: No, it’s because you should not use File. Read contents from InputStream.

Comment: @notyou yes. screenshot attached

Comment: @EladBenda What @duffymo says is true. You **cannot** rely on the `File` object to read the content from a file. When it'll be packaged, you won't be able to read the `file` because it's in your classpath, not your file system

Comment: @duffymo but it fails on file not found. how would you write the code?

Comment: No, src/test/resources is in the classpath.  You should load relative to resources.

Comment: @duffymo how would you write the code?

Comment: @Duffymo: Your comment is not really helpful. You can load an InputStream either by File/Path construct (new FileInputStream( new File( "./../cfg/myRes.txt")), etc.) or by getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/cfg/myRes.txt"). Former relys on the SYSTEM PATH variable for resolving,  latter uses the (java) CLASSPATH of the application.

Comment: Sorry, your comment adds nothing. Yes, I know how file system and class path work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never depend on `File`.  Load `InputStream` from classpath.

Both src/main/resources and src/test/resources are in the classpath if you use the Maven standard directory structure.

I tend to like the Apache Commons IO library and Spring `ClassPathResource`.

Comment: I get NPE for this code:
`            String fileContents = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/test/resources/SenegalAndBulgariaConfig.txt"));
`

Comment: I think I explained that src/test/resources is in class path. Take that out and leave the rest.  Should be "SenegalAndBulgariaConfig.txt".

Comment: Don't you want to make sure that the input stream you get back is not null before you try to read?

Comment: I agree with all (+1) but we can do very well the task without Apache Commons IO library and without Spring.

Comment: Why should anything under "src/" be in the classpath?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, it should be `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/SenegalAndBulgariaConfig.txt")`, he doesn't need to include `src/test/resources/` in the path.

Comment: I didn’t make them required. The idea is the same. I said how I did it. That’s why I didn’t post code.

Answer (score 1):

```
private String readFileContent(String filePath) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filePath).toURI()));
    return new String(bytes);
}
```

in your case filePath will be SenegalAndBulgariaConfig.txt.

for example:

```
String senegalAndBulgariaConfig = readFileContent("SenegalAndBulgariaConfig.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete "src" from the fileContents String.

Answer (score 0):

There is often a confusion between loading files as resources (through classpath) or by addressing it directly on the drive. Maybe my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865168/deploying-text-files-with-java-where-should-they-be-located/45869544#45869544) can help you distiguish the both.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, assuming that `SenegalAndBulgariaConfig.txt` is in `/resources`:

```
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/SenegalAndBulgariaConfig.txt");
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(is, writer, Charset.defaultCharset());
    String fileContents = writer.toString();
    System.out.println(fileContents );
```

**NOTE** `getClass()` can be replaced by `ClassName.class`

Comment: Where does IOUtils come from??

Comment: Apache Commons IO